# How to display validation error for a spinner widget similar to TextView.setError()

Tags: android, validation, spinner

How to display validation error for a spinner widget similar to TextView.setError()
I don't want to open a new dialog box for every spinner validation error, 
android.widget.Spinner class doesn’t have setError method

Answer (score 19):

If your spinner is set-up with default item views the [`getSelectedView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#getSelectedView%28%29) method on Spinner class will return a `TextView`.  And on that you can call [`setError(CharSequence)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) Here is what I did:

```
View selectedView = spinner.getSelectedView();
if (selectedView != null && selectedView instanceof TextView) {
    TextView selectedTextView = (TextView) selectedView;
    if (!valid) {
        String errorString = selectedTextView.getResources().getString(mErrorStringResource);
        selectedTextView.setError(errorString);
    }
    else {
        selectedTextView.setError(null);
    }
}
```

Result looks like this on Android 4.4:

[image: Spinner with error]

Comment: How to set spinner default value, because every time I call spinner.getSelectedView() I got null , because nothing is selected on my spinner.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat cleaner way of doing Diederik's code:

```
static public void setSpinnerError(Spinner spinner, String error){
    View selectedView = spinner.getSelectedView();
    if (selectedView != null && selectedView instanceof TextView) {
        TextView selectedTextView = (TextView) selectedView;
        selectedTextView.setError(error);
    }
}
```

Just set `error` to `null` if you want to dismiss it.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can use 'setError' in your getView in the adapter of spinner. Of course, if your item's xml of your spinner has a TextView:

```
if(requeriedField && item.getValue() == 0){
    img_tittle_spinner.setError(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.FieldRequired));
}
```